# Altova Stylevision 2011 inserting &#x200b; zero width space blocks

Tags: xml, xsl-fo, altova, stylevision

Using an old 2011 version of Altova StyleVision:

Editing a file definition, I export the document to XSL-FO and get inline zero width spaces added that were not in the previous version of the file.

```
<fo:inline-container>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
    </fo:block>
</fo:inline-container>
```

This adds extra unwanted vertical space in the generated output.

I can manually remove this ... but would like to know what causes it and how to avoid it happening in the future.

The only information I have been able to find is on the [Altova Forums](http://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1000002361) which states this cannot be done. I hope this is wrong.

Comment: I would write a simple identity-translate template that just excludes fo:inline-container. Apply that template to your exported FO before formatting.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - I'm in a multi-dev environment and dev is to be handed over to a third party soon, so that would add a layer of complexity that would be bound to go wrong. 

I am more interested in discovering what triggers the block and working with it or avoiding generating it. My thoughts were there may be an option somewhere that generates a blank line between tables / paragraphs.

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth ... (1) It's an old version of Altova and (2) that structure would likely be ignored by most XSL FO formatting engine as they do not support fo:inline-container. Or perhaps (3) when Altova created that old version of software, most all XSL FO processors didn;t support it so it didn't affect the output.

Comment: Thanks Kevin ... it may well be multiple old versions of code in an old codebase with no hope of update

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Set the XSL-FO Generation to "Full usage of XSL-FO standard" on the XSL Options tab of the options.